# JGraphX - Want Entire Graph to be Uneditable

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx

I couldn't find an answer in the manual, or on SO. I want to make a graph with JGraphX that displays some verices and edges, but I don't want the user to be able to move anything around, nor for those green edit boxes to appear on the vortexes or edges. It's just for display only.

I tried this modification of the "Hello World" example to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
package com.mxgraph.examples.swing;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.util.mxConstants;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxStylesheet;

public class HelloWorld extends JFrame
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2707712944901661771L;

public HelloWorld()
{
    super("Hello, World!");

    mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

            //my addition of a stylesheet, I used it on the first node to see if it mad
            //a difference, it didn't regarding dragability//////////////////////////////
    mxStylesheet stylesheet = graph.getStylesheet();
    Hashtable<String, Object> style = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    style.put(mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE, mxConstants.SHAPE_ELLIPSE);
    style.put(mxConstants.STYLE_OPACITY, 50);
    style.put(mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR, "#774400");
    style.put(mxConstants.STYLE_EDITABLE, false);
    stylesheet.putCellStyle("ROUNDED", style);

            //tried this too///////////////////////////////////////////////
    graph.setCellsEditable(false); 

    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try
    {
        Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Hello", 20, 20, 80,
                30, "ROUNDED");
        Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150,
                80, 30);
        graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
    }
    finally
    {
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }

    mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
    getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HelloWorld frame = new HelloWorld();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 320);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable the whole graph component `mxGraphComponent`:

```
graphComponent.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could override `isCellSelectable` to prevent cell selection

```
mxGraph graph = new mxGraph() {

    @Override
      public boolean isCellSelectable(Object cell) {
         if (cell != null) {
            if (cell instanceof mxCell) {
               mxCell myCell = (mxCell) cell;
               if (myCell.isEdge())
                  return false;
            }
         }
         return super.isCellSelectable(cell);
      }
};
```